# PollingDuplexHttpBinding faulted after 5 or 6 calls

Tags: .net, wcf, pollingduplexhttpbinding

I have Implemented polling duplex in silverlight 4 application for getting large amounts of data using client call backs from server, so my service contains some functions with client call backs and some with out call backs. When only 3 or 4 functions called parallel it was working fine, when more than 5 or 6 parallel calls are there i am getting ServerTooBusyException (Service is too busy).

After setting  serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="10000" maxConcurrentInstances="10000" maxConcurrentSessions="10000" values also, I am unable to fix the problem.

When I apply basichttpbinding to service everything is working fine, but when pollingDuplexHttpBinding is aplied its giving error

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ReliableSessionElement.MaxPendingChannels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.servicemodel.configuration.reliablesessionelement.maxpendingchannels%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). Here is [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417496/how-do-i-set-reliablesession-maxpendingchannels-when-i-create-a-nettcpbinding-in). BTW May be it will be good to think about [how to process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130331/how-to-handle-wcf-exceptions-consolidated-list-with-code) that exception when the time comes.